# Azure App Service : can't save application settings

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I can set my application settings and connection strings but I can't save them. The button remains disabled despite my changes. 
I have 3 applications, only one is concerned. I'm admin of the subscription, any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

To overstep this "Azure Portal" problem, you can set your application settings and connexion strings using powerShell, here is a short example :

```
Login-AzureRmAccount

$siteName = 'myWebsiteName';
$rgName = 'myWebsite-resourceGroup';

$appSettings = @{};
$appSettings.Add("myKey","myValue");

Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $siteName -AppSettings $appSettings
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in the new portal, the old one https://manage.windowsazure.com lets me save my changes.
I've send a bug report to Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable adblock and disconnect browser extensions to be able to save the changes

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, turns out that clearing my browser's cache made it work. Looks like a bug on the portal's front end.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this two weeks ago. For me it turned out to be just a lag/propagation issue, the next day the correct changes had been saved and propagated through the system. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

came across this issue in 2017... in chrome, tried edge and it worked