# Unable to save Application Settings in Azure Function App which I was able to save successfully previously

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am getting an error message while trying to save application settings which I have added for the Function App.

I had created a function app and have been using it for Azure functions. I had previously successfully added Application setting for a config parameter in the azure function application settings and have been using this in code. This time when I went to add another application settings suddenly it started giving the error "Cannot change the site to the App Service Plan EastUSPlan due to hosting constraints".  Nothing has been changed and on previous occassions, I was able to add application settings this way.  I have tried following the solutions in below link on using previous or pre URL for azure functions and also to clear cache and try on different browsers.

[Azure App Service : can't save application settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523124/azure-app-service-cant-save-application-settings)

I want to successfully save a new config property in azure function as I was doing previously by adding an entry under Application Settings. How can I save the application settings entry in such a case?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative workaround which worked for me was to delete the function app, create a new function app by the same name, add the application settings in the newly created function app (before deploying any code). It allowed me to save the application settings. Only after this, I deployed the code.

Answer (score 0):

For now to unblock yourself you can use REST API :

[**Web Apps - Update Application Settings**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings)

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/config/appsettings?api-version=2016-08-01
```

But Share the screen shot of the error from the portal. Also I may required further information from your side if the issue still persist so that I can get it rectified from portal perspective also.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this but on trying to do this using Azure REST, although the setting got changed. However, the Azure Function started giving "the function runtime cannot start'.  One alternative workaround which worked for me was to delete the function app, create a new function app by the same name, add the application settings and then deploy the code again.

Comment: Thanks Saurav for the update. I am glad it worked. Also could you accept the answer so that it is helpful for others in the stack community.

Comment: As I had mentioned above, the solution which worked for me was to delete the function app, create a new function app by the same name, add the application settings in the newly created function app (before deploying any code).